# TypeScript (Deno) неправильно выводит типы

Tags: typescript, типы

Написал функцию мемоизации, которая принимает на вход функцию и возращает функцию с такой же сигнатурой

Deno выдает мне следующую ошибку:

> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T>'.deno-ts(2322)

```
function memoized<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(fn: T) {

  type Cache = {[key: string]: ReturnType<T>}

  const cache: Cache = {}

  return function(...args: Parameters<T>) {

    const key = JSON.stringify(args)
    if(key in cache) return cache[key]
    const value = fn(...args)
    return cache[key] = value // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T>'.deno-ts(2322)

  }
}
```

почему то тайпчекер считает, что функция fn возращает буквально unknown. Я же прописал обобщенный тип T который расширает (...args: unknown[]) => unknown, что же тут не так?..

Comment: Попробуйте скобки вокруг типа функции в extends написать

Comment: @AlexeyTen пробовал уже. Пробовал выносить в отдельный тип `type Func = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown`, пробовал тип CallableFunction, пробовал вообще убрать дженерики и пробовал any. Не работает

Я бы мог прибегнуть к грязным приведениям с помощью `as` чтобы всё просто работало, но это уже дело принципа написать как надо или понять, почему я неправ перед компилятором

Comment: Хм, кажется надо не выпендриваться, а использовать any в сигнатуре функции

Comment: @AlexeyTen, нафига там скобки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function memoized<T extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: T): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {

  type Cache = {[key: string]: ReturnType<T>};

  const cache: Cache = {};

  return function (...args: Parameters<T>[]): ReturnType<T> {
    const key: string = JSON.stringify(args);
    if (key in cache) {
        return cache[key];
    } 
    const value = fn(...args);
    return cache[key] = value;
  }

}

// tests
type Concatinate = (a: number, b: number) => string;
const fn: Concatinate = function(a: number, b: number): string {
    return `${a}${b}`;
};

const memoizedFn = memoized<Concatinate>(fn);
memoizedFn(1, 1);
memoizedFn(1, 2);
memoizedFn(1, 3);
```

Comment: [Почистил типы.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=27&pln=7&pc=44#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKbLjAXqgJgHgBVFUAPKVMXAZ0QAoA6JgQwCcBzagLkWbAE8AlIgC8APl4CxdYGB6FBPRiw7dEABTbM0FVtSJjh4xACVUUEKzCF+AB1QHEAbwCwAKHeJEUO6kQBhZggACz8RZwBtAGtUfh5qKFYYMHYAXR4zCysbewMAXwBud09ECAQE0qDQnkCQsOdC4rcvVnNLJFBIWAR6JgY2Th5NVm1zVD0DCNThV2avUvKoRBi4xASklNFEACkAZQB5ADkGdeT2GGB+OgHqQSK5rwv6FcRkyrqZkvn51qykCCqqGisVS92+eUQXwWYAqADdmAAbED1WTKfqqO5Q37td6hYH8VJbeFI1BgxB5JoUjxuMowpayLadaDwMDXHhgEDIABG4wANIguezOTzWJ8HohsVZEAADAAkTmYeXlXLy0vujWptIqaAw2DwADEkOEdZgcLgZGBMW4TXrcIa6ABGfkOq02s32p2IABMrvQpoNrM9AGY7kA)

Comment: Вообще, способ несколько громоздкий, но по сравнению с моим плюс в том, что количество generic-параметров не выросло.

Answer (score 0):

[Песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKbLjAXqgJgHgEFFUAPKVMXAZ0QEMwBPAbQF0AaRAJQD4AKYGABciPgDoJdAE4BzaiMIBKRAF4e3ZQG8AsAChEiCAmpRDdCAAtUIzcwDWqRiJNSYYGaxFdEAX1WIAeQAjACtUaDEIKVQ6Cj4wEAAbRMU9PQNoqBApJFBIWARxSVl5RCVEHX0DQ2NTB0Z-ACkAZQCAOTEXNxkYYEY+aTlUqoNe0XrENzNLVGVM7KQIcyt7R1Z06vmc6ZX61n9BIrFB6mGDHz0fIA)

```
function memoized<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R) {
  const cache: { [key: string]: R } = Object.create(null)

  return function(...args: A) {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args)
    if (key in cache) return cache[key]
    return cache[key] = fn(...args)
  }
}
```